# Handling Optional API Query String Params

Tags: javascript

I am working with the Github API in React and have a form that allows a user to search repositories from 3 different categories: text (as in any repositories that have that text in their name), stars (as in the minimum number of stars), and license type.

The search can be done with any combination of these 3 categories.

So I have the following api fetch function:

```
const root = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='

export const githubSearch = (txt, starMin, license) => {
  return fetch(`${root}${txt}+stars:>=${starMin || 0}`)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      }
      else {
        Promise.reject('Network failure')
      }
    })
}
```

This works fine for the text and star qualifiers because the starMin can be set to a default of 0, and if the text argument is an empty string, it will just skip over it and go to the stars qualifier, but the problem is, the license qualifier needs to have a prefix of 'license:', so, for example:

```
license:mit
```

And leaving the license as an empty string results in a bad request when the following query is performed:

```
fetch(`${root}${txt}+stars:>=${starMin || 0}+license:${license}`)
```

What is the preferred way to handle this optional param? I can think of several hacky ways to do it with setting a new variable conditionally, but that is a major code smell.

BONUS QUESTION: As of right now, if the txt string is empty and the query taking place should just be for star minimum, the resulting url would look something like:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=+stars:>=5
```

It works, but according to the docs, the way to search for stars is like this, **without** the *+* after *=*:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=5
```

Is that considered bad practice?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but you need to `return` that rejected promise or use `throw 'Network failure'` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in an array and join by `+`. If no value, don't put in the array. This way, you don't get the extra `+` for non-existent values.

```
const segments = []
if (txt) segments.push(`${txt}`)
if (license) segments.push(`license:${license}`)
segments.push(`stars:>=${starMin || 0}`)

fetch(`${root}${segments.join('+')}`)
```

Comment: Thanks! That absolutely works. I will mark this as the correct answer but just want to see if any other suggestions come in, but I believe this is the best way.